# Is there an API for using react-navigation's code to parse my deep links manually?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5

**Answer: `useLinkTo` directly from the library!**

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-link-to/

---

Due to the way we are handling deep links that are behind authenticated routes, we are currently manually parsing deep links. Can you point me to the method(s) that are used by react-navigation internally that parse the deep link so I can use them for my authenticated routes when react-navigation does not handle them for me?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: `useLinkTo` directly from the library!**

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-link-to/

```js
import { useLinkTo } from '@react-navigation/native';

// ...

function Home() {
  const linkTo = useLinkTo();

  return (
    <Button onPress={() => linkTo('/profile/jane')}>
      Go to Jane's profile
    </Button>
  );
}
```